# This algorithm isn't working properly?(chessboard queen movement)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

first just to give a brief summary of my program, its a chess board. 8 by 8 grid, starting  from the bottom row to the top row and from left column
to right column , A to H.

**SAMPLE INPUT: TRIAL 1**

```
============
Test.
Qh8 is attacking the target on Xb2
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
N . . . . . . . 
. . B . K . . R 
. . . . . . . . 
. X . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

In this case Queen is able to attack because X is not at the very left bottom of the grid. but the problem is I cant reach the last value at the bottom left of the grid same for other cases please see them to help you understand better what I'm running into.

**SAMPLE INPUT : TRIAL 2**

```
============
Test.
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
N . B . K . . R 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
X . . . . . . .
```

This is what I meant as I said above Queen cant reach the X value

**THIS IS JUST TO EXPLAIN WHAT I MEAN**

**CASE 1:**

```
============
Test.
Qa8 is attacking the target on Xh1
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . B . K . . R 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
N . . . . . . X
```

Works! Queen is able to attack X

NOTICE: only in this case its working in my algorithm not sure why but the other ones don't.

**CASE 2:**

```
============
Test.
. . . . . . . X 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
N . B . K . . R 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
Q . . . . . . .
```

Doesn't work, Queen cant attack X

**CASE 3:**

```
Test.
X . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . B . K . . R 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
N . . . . . . Q
```

This doesn't work either, Queen cant attack X?

**SOURCE CODE**

```
 public void ableToAttack(){



        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
          for(int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++){

             grid[row][column] = ".";
             grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97] = "Q";
             grid[7-rook.charAt(2)+49][(int)rook.charAt(1)-97] = "R";
             grid[7-bishop.charAt(2)+49][(int)bishop.charAt(1)-97] = "B"; 
             grid[7-king.charAt(2)+49][(int)king.charAt(1)-97] = "K";
             grid[7-knight.charAt(2)+49][(int)knight.charAt(1)-97] = "N";
             grid[7-target.charAt(2)+49][(int)target.charAt(1)-97] = "X";

             }
        }

            //HELLO FRIENDS THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK ON THIS METHOD
            int moveRow = 0;
            int moveColumn = 0;
        for( int takeSteps = 0; takeSteps < 8; takeSteps++){
            moveRow++;
             moveColumn++;
           //South east Diaognal Algorithm
          if (inBoard(convRow(target),convCol(target))) {
                if ((convRow(target) == convRow(queen)+moveRow) && (convCol(target) == convCol(queen)+moveColumn))  {
                    System.out.println(queen + " is attacking the target on "+target);
                }

            }
          //North West diagonal Algorithm
          if (inBoard(convRow(target),convCol(target))) {
                if ((convRow(target) == convRow(queen)-moveRow) && (convCol(target) == convCol(queen)-moveColumn))  {
                    System.out.println(queen + " is attacking the target on "+target);
                }

            }

         // North East diaognal Algorithm
           if (inBoard(convRow(target),convCol(target))) {
                if ((convRow(target) == convRow(queen)-moveRow) && (convCol(target) == convCol(queen)+moveColumn))  {
                    System.out.println(queen + " is attacking the target on "+target);
                }

            }
          // South West diagonal Algorithm
           if (inBoard(convRow(target),convCol(target))) {
                if ((convRow(target) == convRow(queen)+moveRow) && (convCol(target) == convCol(queen)-moveColumn))  {
                    System.out.println(queen + " is attacking the target on "+target);
                }

            }

        }

        for(int row = 0; row <grid.length; row++){
          for(int column = 0; column <grid[row].length; column++){
        System.out.printf("%2s",grid[row][column] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }



        }

        private boolean inBoard(int row, int col) {
            return (row <= 8)
                    && (row >= 1)
                    && (col <= 8)
                    && (col >= 1);
        }

        private int convRow(String rowz) {
            return 7-rowz.charAt(2)+49;
        }

        private int convCol(String columnz) {
            return columnz.charAt(1)-97;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740616/how-can-i-check-if-queen-is-able-to-attack-the-x-position-but-not-moving-it-t/43740955#43740955

How many accounts do you have and how many times are you going to ask for the same questions

```
    private boolean inBoard(int row, int col) {
        return (row <= 8)
                && (row >= 1)
                && (col <= 8)
                && (col >= 1);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure this function is wrong, in Java Arrays start to 0, and your table length is 8, so it's between 0 and 7 included.

Must be :

```
private boolean inBoard(int row, int col) {
            return (row <= 7)
                    && (row >= 0)
                    && (col <= 7)
                    && (col >= 0);
        }
```

Comment: ignore the comment i did and I think you're right I will do it

Comment: Try to fix your inBoard function and tell us if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Yes ! thank you so much my friend, I'm so sorry If i bothered you but I finally got my problem working because of you thanks <3. Also Sorry if im annoying I'm a beginner and in grade 11

Answer (score 1):

Your inBoard algorithm is off by one. Your board array is 0-7, not 1-8

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the time to understand your algorithm, but i would do it like:

```
if(Dame_row == Q_row){
   //now go through the distance in a loop, if nothing is in the way, return true
}else if(Dame_col == Q_col){
  //now go through the distance in a loop, if nothing is in the way, return true    
}else if(Math.abs(Dame_row - Q_row) == Math.abs(Dame_col - Q_col)){
  //now go through the distance in a loop, if nothing is in the way, return true  
}
return false;
```

Comment: But my program ignore blocking, so it doesnt matter whats in the way. is it  something wrong with my moveRow or moveColumn ? or the loop how many times it goes up to ?